# MiniTest Tutorials in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

are there any good tutorials on MiniTest in rails. 
was searching for a while bt without much success.
any help would be really welcome...

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/327-minitest-with-rails and 
http://blowmage.com/2012/07/10/announcing-minitest-rails

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Announcing Minitest Rails](http://blowmage.com/2012/07/10/announcing-minitest-rails) to get started.

After you've picked up the basics and some syntax, I recommend reading the [RSpec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book). It uses RSpec but really teaches you general testing techniques which can be applied in multiple testing frameworks.

And when you forget something, you can refer to [cheatsheets](http://www.mattsears.com/articles/2011/12/10/minitest-quick-reference).